# How to make INSERT fail on a table that has foreign key to another table when the row contains some specific value?

Tags: mysql, database, constraints, relational-database

I'm sorry if the title is confusing (which it is, likely). Let me give you an example similar to my case.

So for example I have `users` table with fields `id`, `user_type`, and `name`.

Another table is `videos` with fields `id`, `title`, and `user_id` referencing to `users.id`. I want `INSERT` to `videos` to fail when `videos.user_id` references `users` row that the value of `user_type` is 'a', for example.

Comment: 'is 'a', for example' - if no a what else can it be for example?

Comment: can you please `SHOW CREATE TABLE videos` ?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's support for database constraints is not expressive enough to allow this kind of constraint rule to be built into your data definition.

You could consider using a BEFORE INSERT trigger, or consider building this kind of rule in to your application.